# Formula to create values: FYnn when fiscal years not on calendar boundaries

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I'm creating a custom campaign naming convention and I need one part of the IF statements to return a fiscal year text value equal to "FY17","FY18", etc.

So, the logic is: If the date is between 7/1/16 and 6/30/17 then the text value returned is "FY17", etc.

This code needs to be built into an IF statement that is already differentiating between Opportunity Account Names.

Please let me know if any other information needs to be provided.

Comment: Is your org already using the platform's [Fiscal Year](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_about_cfy.htm) functionality for forecasting, reporting, etc.?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "This code needs to be built into an IF statement that is already differentiating between Opportunity Account Names."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

`'FY' & RIGHT(TEXT( YEAR( My_Date__c ) + IF( MONTH( My_Date__c ) > 6, 1, 0)), 2)`